# Wordpress check with 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-500

I am new in wordpress and my site is down. After lots of research I get to know there may be some syntax error.

Can you please help to find is there any syntax error in code or not

My code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML 500 response code is a server error. The first thing you should do is check your `error_log` to find out what the error is. Look at a page with `phpinfo();` and search for `error_log`, it will give you the path.

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to -1, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

Once you have the error message, update your question or leave a comment on this answer and we will take it forward!

Comment: This is my error ` PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/microso6/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Awesome! So now you know that PHP failed to find the file `/home/microso6/public_html/index.php`. Can you confirm the file actually exists in that location?

Comment: Yes, File is exists  in that location. But while opening file it is empty. I mean nothing is der to edit or something.

Comment: an empty index.php? Stick a <?= phpinfo(); ?> in it and see if it displays.

Comment: Well I placed `<?=phpinfo()>` and in error I am getting `[29-Aug-2017 11:54:59 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[29-Aug-2017 11:54:59 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/data/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Ok, now it begins to look like permissions errors. Which user runs the script? www-data? apache? You probably need to `chmod` or `chown` your site folders

Comment: well.. ok I am checking what those means are. I mean I am completely new here. I find the page. Let me check what permission error have. Thanks for help :)

Comment: cd into the folder and type `ls -la` to see the owner, group, and permissions

Comment: I am using window and do I need to open terminal.